# How can I keep track of each object in an array's health in a Java game?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on learning how to program Java games.  Right now I am working on a very simple game, a starting point for a more advanced game.  I'm trying to learn how to implement things like reputation into a game, so I can add it to a more advanced RPG later.
My first step was going to be to add an ability for the player to attack the NPC's that I set up.  It would then lower the player's reputation.  I used an array to create the NPC's like follows.  I haven't shown the class or constructor for the NPC's, but there is both a getHealth and setHealth method, among others available.
This is where I set up the NPC's:

```
          int NPCS = 10;
          NPC[] npc = new NPC[NPCS];
```

Then, in my init() method:

```
        for(int n = 0; n < NPCS; n++){
        npc[n] = new NPC();
        npc[n].setX((double)rand.nextInt(1240 + 20));
        npc[n].setY((double)rand.nextInt(920 + 20));
        npc[n].setHealth(100);
    }
```

I have other methods for controlling the NPC's (like a drawNPCS method), but I only put these to explain how the NPC's are added.  This sets up the NPC's just fine.  I can cause the NPC's to move in a random direction after a certain amount of time, and they all move individually, in different directions.  However, if I try to check the distance between an npc[n] and the player, it will only check the distance between a single npc[n].  That is where my real question comes in.  Right now I check the distance like this:

```
public void checkDistance(){
    for(int n = 0; n < NPCS; n++){
        if(Math.abs(player.getX() - npc[n].getX()) <= 48 && Math.abs(player.getY() - npc[n].getY()) <= 48){
            canAttack = true;
        }else if (!(Math.abs(player.getX() - npc[n].getX()) <= 48 && Math.abs(player.getY() - npc[n].getY()) <= 48)){
            canAttack = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The Boolean only changes when I am near a specific NPC, not any of them.  Also, if I add a spacebar control:

```
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        if(canAttack = true){
            for(int n = 0; n < NPCS; n++){
                npc[n].setHealth(npc[n].getHealth() - 10);
            }
        }
```

All of the NPC's are affected, while only one of them are able to be attacked.  With this setup, I can only attack one of the NPC's, then when its health is at 0, they all disappear.  How can I keep the array to draw the NPC's, but track the health for them all?  I would really like to keep them all the same, in the same array, at least for now, so I don't have to create constructors for all of the NPC's, because the code would get really hectic.  Thanks!

Comment: Note `if(canAttack = true)` should be `if(canAttack == true)` or more simple `if(canAttack)`

Comment: Right... that's a good point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're changing your `canAttack` variable `n` times in your `checkDistance()` function. You're checking it for every single NPC, so you'll get a bunch of falses and a bunch of trues. The only one that will MATTER is the NPC that comes last.

For example, for 3 NPCs, where `Player` is near NPC 1 only, your code will go:

```
NPC 1 -> canAttack = true
NPC 2 -> canAttack = false
NPC 3 -> canAttack = false
```

So net result is `canAttack` is false. A solution is to add a `canAttack` field to your `NPC` object definition, then set each object to having a `canAttack` value on your loop. I think a better name for this variable would be `canBeAttacked` but that's just my opinion from what I've read of your code.

PS. As @ZouZou points out in the comment above, you should use `==` to compare booleans. Use `=` only for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have the canAttack value inside the NPC class and set

```
NPC.canAttack = true
```

or add a method in the NPC class to set the attack value to true.

As it stands you're running through the loop within a fraction of a second ending only on NPC[10] which either can or cannot attack and that sets the canAttack value... which isn't unique to that NPC.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little game to. If your game takes a lot of code, I would recommend the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).
To solve your problem, simply store canAttack in your NPC. This way, you will be able to attack multiple NPCs and control which one.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep track of which NPC has the highest priority as a target with possible factors such as who is in range of my weapon, who is closest, who has already attacked me, who have I already attacked, who has me in range of their weapon, or other such concepts.

You might benefit from creating an AdjustHealth(chg) method, rather than set(get()-damage).